# Connection Refused - Redis for Data Protection Keys in ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, redis, data-protection

I'm going through this article from Microsoft: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I am trying to do the following:

```
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToRedis(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost"));
```

Error Stack:

```
app    | Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
app    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
app    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Boolean flowContext)
app    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.PostOneBeginConnect(MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context)
app    | --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
app    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoMultipleAddressConnectCallback(Object result, MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context)
app    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoDnsCallback(IAsyncResult result, MultipleAddressConnectAsyncResult context)
app    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
app    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port)
app    |    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketTaskExtensions.ConnectAsync(Socket socket, String host, Int32 port)
app    |    at StackExchange.Redis.SocketManager.BeginConnect(EndPoint endpoint, ISocketCallback callback, ConnectionMultiplexer multiplexer, TextWriter log) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\SocketManager.cs:line 194
```

I am using Docker:

```
redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the container and port

```
services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToRedis(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("redis:6379"));
```

I also added abortConnect=false" to configuration

```
REDIS_CONNECTION_STRING = "redis:6379,abortConnect=false"


var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIS_CONNECTION_STRING"));
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");
```